# Rename in Ionic select button cancel and ok

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working with the Ionic Framework.

In all of my forms i am using the ionic select do display some options.
It works perfectly. But its showing 2 buttons in english: cancel and okay.

I would like to rename this buttons in another names due to the language.
Where can i do this? I looked and searched the whole directory but could not find anything. It looks like the ionic is building them somehow. Or do i need some more js to rename this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the manual at https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/

> By default, the two buttons read Cancel and OK. Each button's text can be customized using the cancelText and okText attributes:

```
<ion-select okText="Okay" cancelText="Dismiss">
  ...
</ion-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

okText actually didn't work with my Ionic 5.4.4 version. I used doneText instead and worked just fine.